# Creating paramaterized query using asp, getting value or the wrong type error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, parameters

So I am trying to create a page that will query a database and return the results. basically, in the URL if you put in `000.000.000.000/sql/products.asp?id=1` then the database will return with the product id and name. The error comes on the line where I say 
    `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@id", AdInteger, adParamInput, 1000)` If I put `AdInteger`, I get an error saying

```
ADODB.Command error "800a0d5d" application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.
```

If I put `adVarChar` instead, the query runs but it just says no products found. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks for your time.

```
 <!--METADATA
 TYPE="TypeLib"
NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.6 Library"
UUID="{00000206-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}"
VERSION="2.6"
-->
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
   <HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ProductScript</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<%
 dim id, query
 dim conn, rs, cmd
 Id = Request.QueryString("id")

Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Global = true
regEx.pattern = "[^0-9a-zA-Z]"
Id = regEx.Replace(request.form("id"), "")


set conn = server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=10.4.13.117; Initial   Catalog=CIS_ZZZ; User Id=myUserName; Password=myPasswordValue"
rs.activeConnection = conn


with cmd
 .ActiveConnection = conn
 .Commandtext = "SELECT prodName FROM products WHERE id = ?"
 .CommandType = adCmdText
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@id", AdVarChar, adParamInput, 1000)
 .Parameters("@id") = id
end with
response.write cmd.commandText & "<p>"
set rs = Cmd.Execute

if not rs.eof then
 response.write "Got product " & rs.fields("prodName").value
else
 response.write "No product found"
end if

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd bet that you get that error because id is a string.  Try explicitly converting it to an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
So i figured out what is happening i think. When i delete the Regular expression then it seems to work just fine. But when i put the regular expression back in it goes back to string. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: regex.replace() returns a string.  The only way I can think is to try to convert the result back to an integer explicitly.